# Client Server Logs Shows Public IP instead of Spoof IP in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

As the title says, I have been tasked to do Load and Performance Testing on a Client's Server, I have followed all steps, made additional IPs and added it to the system, and entered the same IPs in Jmeter using CSV dataset, and Debug Postproccessor shows that the request is being sent with the correct IPs. I am doing this over wifi, so hopefully that isn't the issue.
Any help is appreciated.

System config
OS: Windows 10 64 bit
Ram: 16gb
Jmeter Version 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

It may easily happen if you're behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and the server is in the Internet, in that case no matter what is your local IP address(es), the server will "see" only the address of your NAT gateway, you can check yourself using websites like https://www.whatismyip.com/

The trick with local IP addresses (or [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing)) will succeed only in case of local [intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet), when it comes to Internet - you will need to have as many **global static IP addresses** as many users you're trying to simulate.

One of the possible solutions is kicking off virtual machines in AWS or Azure or similar service or asking your ISP to provide you a pool of IP addresses you could use (normally you will need to pay for this) and go for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter) so each JMeter slave would have its own IP address (or several) to bind.